# How to Determine Session ID when using SQL Sever session storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I followed [this guide](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/292/configuring-sql-server-for-session-state-in-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc) to set up Sql Server as my store for Session data.

I noticed the Sessions table has an ID column. I was hoping I could use this ID column to determine the current session (row in the Sessions table) being used. However, I don't know how this ID is generated or how ASP.NET Core behind the scenes matches this ID to the Session.

I tried using `HttpContext.Session.Id`, but it is different from the ID in the database.

So, how do I determine which row is being used for the Session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's randomly generated. You can see this in the [middleware source](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/SessionMiddleware.cs)

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionKey) || sessionKey.Length != SessionKeyLength)
        {
            // No valid cookie, new session.
            var guidBytes = new byte[16];
            CryptoRandom.GetBytes(guidBytes);
            sessionKey = new Guid(guidBytes).ToString();
            cookieValue = CookieProtection.Protect(_dataProtector, sessionKey);
            var establisher = new SessionEstablisher(context, cookieValue, _options);
            tryEstablishSession = establisher.TryEstablishSession;
            isNewSessionKey = true;
        }
```