# For what design reason is Asp.Net Core SessionKey different than the SessionId?

Tags: sql-server, security, session, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

### Some Background

In asp.net core when using SqlServer to store sessions, oddly enough the `Id` column in the SqlServer table gets set to the value of `sessionKey` which is a `Guid` generated by the [SessionMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/SessionMiddleware.cs#L93).  I say oddly enough because there is a `SessionId` but the `Id` in the table isn't set to that, it is set to the `SessionKey`.  (I'm not making this up)

This `sessionKey` used for the `Id` in the table is also the value that is encrypted and placed in the session cookie. Here is that `SessionMiddleware` code:

```
 var guidBytes = new byte[16];
 CryptoRandom.GetBytes(guidBytes);
 sessionKey = new Guid(guidBytes).ToString();
 cookieValue = CookieProtection.Protect(_dataProtector, sessionKey);
 var establisher = new SessionEstablisher(context, cookieValue, _options);
 tryEstablishSession = establisher.TryEstablishSession;
 isNewSessionKey = true;
```

The `SessionId` however, is a `Guid` generated by the [DistributedSession object](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/DistributedSession.cs#L90) in the following line of code:

```
_sessionId = new Guid(IdBytes).ToString();
```

Interestingly the `ISession` interface provides a property for the `SessionId` but not the `SessionKey`.  So it's often much easier in code to get access to a `SessionId` then a `SessionKey`, for example when you have access to an `HttpContext` object.

This makes it hard to match up the session to the database record if you desire to do that. This was noted by another user on stackoverflow as well [How to Determine Session ID when using SQL Sever session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664567/how-to-determine-session-id-when-using-sql-sever-session-storage/40684705).

### Why?

What I want to know is why is the system designed this way?  Why isn't the `SessionId` and `SessionKey` the one and the same?  Why use two different `Guids`?  I ask because I'm creating my own implementation of `ISession` and I'm tempted to use the `SessionKey` as the `SessionId` in my implementation so that it's easier to match up a record in the database to a session.  Would that be a bad idea?  Why wan't `DistributedSession` object designed that way rather than generating a `SessionId` that is different than the `SessionKey`?  The only reason I can think of is perhaps trying increase security by obfuscating the linkage between the database record and the session it belongs to.  But in general security professionals don't find security through obfuscation effective.  So I'm left wondering why such a design was implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also posted the question on GitHub https://github.com/aspnet/Session/issues/151#issuecomment-287894321 to try to get an answer as well.

@Tratcher answered the question there so I'm pasting his answer below so that it's available here on stackoveflow too.

The lifetimes are different. The true lifetime of a session (and SessionId) is controlled by the server. SessionKey is stored in the cookie and lives on the client for an indeterminate amount of time. If the session expires on the server and then the client sends a new request with the old SessionKey, a new session instance with a new SessionId is created, but stored using the old SessionKey so that we don't have to issue a new cookie.

Put another way, don't depend on things outside of your control. The client can keep and replay their SessionKey indefinitely, but it's the server that decides if that is really still the same session.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone need to get the sessionkey in asp.net core 3

1. Add DI for IDataProtector (IMPORTANT! when create protector it should be nameof(SessionMiddleware))

   ```
   public IDataProtector _dataProtector;

   public TestController( IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider )
   {
       _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(nameof(SessionMiddleware));
   }
   ```
2. Create method which will get proper value for the session cookie

   ```
   private string Pad(string text)
   {
       var padding = 3 - ((text.Length + 3) % 4);
       if (padding == 0)
       {
           return text;
       }
       return text + new string('=', padding);
   }
   ```
3. Use it

   ```
   public ActionResult TestSession(  )
   {

       var protectedText = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[ ".AspNetCore.Session" ];

       var sessionKey = "";
       var protectedData = Convert.FromBase64String(Pad(protectedText));
       if (protectedData == null)
       {
           sessionKey = string.Empty;
       }

       var userData = _dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedData);
       if (userData == null)
       {
           sessionKey = string.Empty;
       }

       sessionKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(userData);

       return Content( sessionKey );
   }
   ```